# json.net serialization/deserialization on an external json file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working with c# within VS2012 and have installed the json.net files to handle the deserialization of a json string that's stored in an external file (1.json). As a newbie, i've come across a situation in which I want to extract information called score and avarage score from a single json string; see below:

```
{"LEVEL": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
"score": 1,
"average score": 2 }
```

The output I get from the debugger once I step through the process shows that the stream only picks up the first part of the json file (everything from the first opening square bracket to the closing square bracket) so I'm unable to obtain the score and average score. Here is what I have at the moment to try to extract this information...

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
{
    levelData = sr.ReadLine();
    var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(levelData);
}
```

Can anyone provide any advice as to how I can extract this information? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading and the file and deserializing data line by line. You cannot do that with json as it is the whole structure (like xml).

Instead you should deserialize the whole file:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(filename);
var stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```